# How to show splash screen while initializing database?

Tags: android

I have created an splash screen, which works perfectly. Now I want to load database while showing splash screen and after database has been loaded completely show the application UI. 
 I have the following code to do this is this right?

```
public class Splash extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    new LoadDatabase().execute();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

// Load DB
protected class LoadDatabase extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, String> 
{ 
     @Override 
     protected String doInBackground( Context... params ) { 
         try {
            new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext()).initializeDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         return "";
     } 

     @Override 
     protected void onPreExecute() { 
        super.onPreExecute(); 
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
     } 

     @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
        super.onPostExecute(result);
         Intent openMain = new Intent("com.nepways.MAIN"); 
         startActivity(openMain); 
    }
}
```

}

Is there any good example or suggestions?? please help me out with this.

Comment: I found tutorial for UI Thread and Background [Processing](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#overview_intro).
and Refer this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979524/android-splashscreen/1982002#1982002).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may perform this operation through async or thread and handler

```
protected class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, String> 
{ 
     @Override 
     protected String doInBackground( Context... params ) 
     { 
      // write ur database functionality 
     } 

     // -- gets called just before thread begins 
     @Override 
     protected void onPreExecute() 
     { 
        // u may show ur progressbar or spalsh screen
        super.onPreExecute(); 

     } 


     // -- called as soon as doInBackground method completes 
     @Override 
     protected void onPostExecute() 
     { 
       super.onPostExecute(result); 
      // Intent openMain = new Intent("com.nepways.MAIN"); 
            startActivity(openMain); 
     } 
}
```

Try this ... may be it will help u

Comment: @Kartik I have edited my whole splash class as u have suggested, is this right?

Comment: yes it will work , just call this from ur oncreate function new MyTask().execute( this );

Answer (score 2):

Invoke an Activity, lets call it SplashScreen. invoke an `AsyncTask` from this activity that accesses another class created by you, extending `SQLiteOpenHelper`. This class initializes the database.
When this AsyncTask finishes working, it returns the control to UI thread, now close the SplashScreen.

Comment: Its demo is here in SO. check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222890/how-to-make-a-splash-screen-screen-visible-when-app-starts

Answer (score 0):

load the data base in a thread and once done go to next screen using handler ,Use handler Class for android .search handler and thread you would get lot of solutions.

Answer (score -1):

In your onCreate of SplashScreen write the following code

```
    myDataBase=this.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    dbHelper.openDataBase();
```

Declare your database details before the constructor

Comment: This will do the initialization on the UI Thread, which could make your application non responsive if it takes longer than a few seconds. Consider using an AsyncTask instead.