# Android: Progress Dialog spinner not spinning

Tags: android, dialog, progress-bar, progress

This seems to be an Android-wide problem, which you can see in API demos under Views -> Progress Bar -> Dialogs.

Basically, if you show a progress dialog, it works as expected the first time around. If you dismiss it and show it again (without destroying the activity or anything like that), the spinning image stops spinning. In the API Demo you can see this by clicking "Show Indeterminate", pressing back to dismiss the dialog, and clicking the button again.

I've tried constructing my own progress dialog, however it shows the same problem, as the problem is with the "ProgressBar" spinning image.

I am wondering if anyone has a workaround for this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231438/progress-dialog-while-starting-new-activity

Can we see some code?  Also have you tried recreating the processdialog each time before it shows?  so something like procDialog = new ProcessDialog(...);

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you dismiss a `Dialog`, you must not show the same instance again. Either create a new one, or use `hide()` instead of `dismiss()`. When using `hide()` you still have to `dismiss()` it when no longer needed.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the same answer, however none of the answers here worked for me because I wanted to use the Activity's dialog methods like `Activity.showDialog()` so I didn't have to manage them myself and also so they would automatically be recreated on a rotation.

Like some of the other answers said, if dismiss() is called on a `ProgressDialog` it will stop spinning. `Activity.onCreateDialog()` saves a reference to the dialog, so once it is created it will not be recreated on the next `Activity.showDialog()` call. It will just call `Activity.onPrepareDialog()` and use the instance it already had.  If it was dismissed then it won't spin when it is showed again.

You can force it to recreate itself if you call `Activity.removeDialog()` with the `ProgressDialog`'s id instead of calling `Dialog.dismiss()`.  This will dismiss it and also remove that reference so when `Activity.onShowDialog()` is called next it will use `Activity.onCreateDialog()` instead of only `Activity.onPrepareDialog()` and create a brand new (and spinning) instance.

Make sure if you have a `ProgressDialog` that can be dismissed or canceled you set a listener so you can call `Activity.removeDialog()`.  Otherwise it will only be dismissed.  You could also call it right before you call `Activity.showDialog()`.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use `onCreateDialog` for `ProgressDialog` objects, as explained here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog . You should create and show the progress dialog in the main code instead of using `showDialog` and `onCreateDialog`.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a `ProgressDialog` instance in your Activity and override `onCreateDialog(int)`. Then instead of making a call to `showDialog(int)` you just assign your instance of `ProgressDialog` the call to `onCreateDialog(int)` where you will call `dialog.show()`.

```
public class Home extends Activity {

ProgressDialog recordingDialog;

//where you want to call the dialog
recordingDialog = (ProgressDialog)onCreateDialog(RECORDING_DIALOG_KEY);


@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    switch (id) {
    case RECORDING_DIALOG_KEY:
        ((ProgressDialog) dialog).setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        ((ProgressDialog) dialog)
                .setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setMessage("Recording...");
        dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Stop",
                dialogStopListener);

        dialog.show();

        break;
    default:
        dialog = null;
    }
    return dialog;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define class and implement the AsyncTask.There you define your background processes in the doinbackground() method like this.

```
 @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
   publishProgress(new Integer(1));
   for(int i=0;i<=300;i++){
System.out.println(i);
}
publishProgress(new Integer(1));
for(int i=301;i<=600;i++){
System.out.println(i);
}
 .................
 ....................
 ...........................
 //your background tasks
publishProgress(new Integer(1));
for(int i=601;i<=900;i++){
System.out.println(i);
}
pd.dismiss();//dismiss the progress dialog here...
return null;
}
```

You can also show your progress information by the onProgressUpdate() method.Check a full easy to follow tutorial at http://www.androidcookers.co.cc/2011/12/want-to-run-progress-dialog-in-android.html