# ProgressBar visibility issue

Tags: android

I have an issue with progressbar's visibility.
Basically,I am passing a intent from activity to another activity after startActivity(intent) line I am setting the visibility of progressbar to invisible.

While,doing this I noticed that progressbar got invisible too early.
I need to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

my code is as below

```
public void GetUserProfileDetails() {

    mLoginFrom = 1;
    bearer = "Bearer " + mResponseAccessToken;
    RestAdapter.Builder restAdapterBuilder = new RestAdapter.Builder();
    if(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
    {
        restAdapterBuilder.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);

    }
    RestAdapter restDetailAdapter = restAdapterBuilder.setEndpoint(FBAPI).build();

   // RestAdapter restDetailAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).setEndpoint(FBAPI).build();

    fetch_profiledetails hit_api = restDetailAdapter.create(fetch_profiledetails.class);
    hit_api.fetchProfileDetails(bearer, mSuperId, new Callback<FetchDetailsPojo>() {
        @Override
        public void success(FetchDetailsPojo fetchDetailsPojo, Response response) {



            mIsnewUser = fetchDetailsPojo.getIsNew();
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainLoginActivity.this).edit().putBoolean(mIsNewUserKey, mIsnewUser).commit();
            is_pin = fetchDetailsPojo.getIsPin();
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainLoginActivity.this).edit().putBoolean("isPin", is_pin).commit();
            mUserUpdatedProfilePic = fetchDetailsPojo.getImageUrl();
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainLoginActivity.this).edit().putString("mupdatedprofilepic", mUserUpdatedProfilePic).commit();

            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainLoginActivity.this).edit().putInt("login", mLoginFrom).commit();

            // mLoginProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //Intent intent = new Intent(MainLoginActivity.this,ActivityUserDetail.class);

           if (mIsnewUser==true){

               Intent intent = new Intent(MainLoginActivity.this, ActivityUserHistory.class);
               startActivity(intent);
               mProgressBarLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

           }else {

               finish();
               Intent intentToMain = new Intent(MainLoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
               startActivity(intentToMain);
               mProgressBarLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

           }


        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

           mProgressBarLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: you can delay that using threads

Comment: Can you post your code.

Comment: [link] added my code.

Comment: so you want to make the progressBar visibility after Intent when the whole layout is loaded am I right?

Comment: yes i want my progessbar to remain visible to user untill another activity is launched

Comment: you cannot do that as stated here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231438/progress-dialog-while-starting-new-activity start the progress dialog on your second activity as you dont have reference for your progress dialog in first activity

Answer (score 1):

Set progress bar invisible in `onStop()` of `Activity`:

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```

If needed in a particular case put a flag while starting new `Activity` and check that flag in `onStop()`.

Answer (score 0):

one way is that using post delay

```
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }, TIMEINMILISECONDS);
```