# Android show ProgressDialog until activity UI finished loading

Tags: android, android-activity

HI,
Im trying to show a ProgressDialog while the activity is loading.
my problem is that although i completed all the work in the activity
it takes a long time for the activity to load, i suspect this is because i use
multiple views with multiple listviews with custom array adapters inside a viewflipper.
it takes a long time for the UI to show.

how would i go about checking that all the UI inside the activity finished loading?

or is there a way to preload all the activity and the UI?

Thanks,

Comment: are you doing the "work" on the same thread as the UI? loading your listviews and what not, on the same thread will block the activity from showing.

Comment: Im doing the work in the on create so i can generate the view and then call setContentView(); however the OnCreate() finishes and also all the calls to OnStart() and OnResume() but i see the UI only about 8 seconds after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Asynctask

```
  new DownloadTask().execute();


  private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> {

    protected void doInBackgroind(Void... arg0){
    //Do time Consuming Processing
    publishProgres()
    return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... arg0){
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void... result){
    log.i("AvtivityInfo", "activity finished loading...");
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure if that will work... I'll have to give it a try by my own.

Comment: How exactly will this help? my problem is that the UI isnt showing up even though the activity already recived all the visible inication messages such as "public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus)"
all the UI stuff is the on create, i suspect the listview adapters are doing something in the backgroud and thats the main issue

Comment: The problem is its not a "task" there is no download or communication or any async operation involved here its only loading the resources from XML and it all happens in the OnCreate which takes less than a second to complete, however the UI is only truly visible after 8 seconds or so.

Comment: try this sample to understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979524/android-splashscreen, display a progressDialog in the UI till the data is completely loaded. if you see the UI after 8 seconds that means there´s a process blocking your UI, maybe your ArrayAdapter loading.

Comment: I agree that the ArrayAdapter loading is whats making the UI not visible, my question is how can i check that tis finished loading?

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(Void... result){
    log.i("AvtivityInfo", "activity finished loading...");
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you think you need a `ProgressDialog` because your activity is opening too slowly, you have much bigger problems. Android is likely to kill off your activity with an activity-not-responding error.

You can either get sophisticated and use [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html) to find your performance issue, or you can just experiment. For example, you can skip setting adapters in your `ListViews`, to confirm that the problem indeed lies there.

Jorgesys had the right answer in his now-deleted entry, from what I can tell. I suspect that loading your adapters is taking the time, perhaps in database queries, and you need to move some of that into `AsyncTasks`.

Comment: Thats the thing there are no DB queries, nothing but work with drawables and layouts. i cant think of what to break up into AsyncTasks because all the work is in the OnCreate which is very fast. Is the ArrayAdapter loading async? and if so is there a way to check when its done loading?

Comment: @totem: "Is the ArrayAdapter loading async?" No.