# Modal HUD on asynctask

Tags: android

I am working on something in Android. There will be a menu, when accessed, requests a fairly large list of users from a server (500+) and takes about 5 seconds. During this time, the application freezes. How do I go about showing a progress hud (like MBProgressHud) where the user is aware something is happening and can't touch out of it until it is complete.

MBProgressHud:

[image: HUD Example]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use AsyncTask :

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Result>{

                        private Activity activity;
                        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            public MyAsyncTask(Activity activity) {
                            super();
                this.activity = activity;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Loading", "Loading", true);
            }

            @Override
            protected Result doInBackground(Void... v) {
            //do your stuff here
            return null;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Finished.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


}
```

Call it from the activity:

```
MyAsyncTask task = new AsyncTask(myActivity.this);
task.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and [`ProgressDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) to achieve this functionality. It will off-load the heavy lifting (web calls) on a separate thread, setting your UI thread to be free from ANR (Application Not Responding).

For more info, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3893691/966550) answer.