# Android Download image from the web using bound Service - Access denied in storin gto sd card

Tags: android, download, filestream, outputstream

Helo, friends i trying to do one image download from the internet using bound services,.through download method i call to bound service class,and through this service one asyctask class is called to display doenload progress through doInBackground(URL... urls) methods. but when `output = new FileOutputStream(Path+"hive.jpg");` is called at that time error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/hive.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)` occure.please help quickly, thanks in advance.

I taking all the permission that required. my menifist file permission :

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

my backgrounds methods code is following:

```
    @Override
protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {

    int count;

        try {
            System.out.println("do in backgrounds");
            URL url = new URL(urls[0].toString());
            System.out.println("utl=" + url);

            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            System.out.println("open connecton+" + conexion);
            conexion.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            System.out.println("input stream=" + input);

            String Path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator;// "/sdcard/";

            System.out.println("PAth=" + Path);

            try {
                output = new FileOutputStream(Path+"hive.jpg");  // exception error here
                System.out.println("output stream=" + output);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Path+"hive.jpg");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            System.out.println("before while");
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                int percent = (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile);
                publishProgress(percent);
                output.write(data, 0, count);
                System.out.println("file write successfulyy");
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
            System.out.println("close function ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    //}
    return null;

}
```

Error/Exception are following:

```
  : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/hive.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:128)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:117)
    at com.example.boundservice2.BackgroundDownload.doInBackground(BackgroundDownload.java:63)
    at com.example.boundservice2.BackgroundDownload.doInBackground(BackgroundDownload.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
   Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
```

Comment: add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in menifest

Comment: @Saqib, read the question properly.

Comment: @user3257401 what error it fires ? can you post error logs ?

Comment: i post error log in above

Comment: Are you using an emulator or a device? If emulator make sure your emulator has space allocated for external storage.

Comment: i already added 500 Mib as internal and sd card storage

Comment: Error : No address associated with hostname One of the Solution : start your internet connection

Comment: I find solution from the below link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code to below code,

```
File file = new File( Path + "hive.jpg" );     // Add this line 
output = new FileOutputStream ( file );

if (!file.exists())                           // Add this code 
{
    file.createNewFile();
}
```

Comment: yes its give same error point to `output = new FileOutputStream ( file );`

Comment: I suggest you to try out your code in real device once.

Comment: Hello good morning kedar, i try it in real device nothing error but image are originally in internet address but error log giving below,

Comment: `04-09 10:49:44.092: I/System.out(14162): utl=http://api.androidhive.info/progressdialog/hive.jpg
04-09 10:49:44.096: I/System.out(14162): open connecton+libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl:http://api.androidhive.info/progressdialog/hive.jpg
04-09 10:49:44.103: D/libc-netbsd(14162): getaddrinfo: api.androidhive.info NO result from proxy 
04-09 10:49:44.104: I/System.out(14162): [CDS][DNS]Unable to resolve host "api.androidhive.info": No address associated with hostname`

Comment: Good Morning, can you give me the link of the tutorial ?

Comment: i generally guide from the andriud github and image link is `"http://api.androidhive.info/progressdialog/hive.jpg"`

Comment: I know that url, but I want url of the tutorial from where you got this code ?

Comment: Hello kedar now it is working fine in real device ..thanks for your responce and your quick answers. i just change the link of image.

Comment: thanks, just minute kedar,i want to put progress bar when time of downloading how i can do because in `BackgroundDownload` class not supporting post execute and other create dialog, really i want to create one apps that download do in background service so activity can not take much weight. when download over progressbar over and service work over return to activity download load is over so when i put code of progressbar n as i say above

Comment: you can do it in AsyncTask, too. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3893691/3330969

Comment: hello kedar i so much tried but not got at the solution u give me any example of bound service that download image display in progressbar and at the over progress dismiss using only bound service ???

Comment: did you check that answer ?