# How to show progress bar efficiently?

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-download-manager

In my XML I have this progress bar but after download gets over it is rotating.How to attach this progress bar with my download code.

```
   <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginTop="153dp" />
```

This is how I am downloading my files:

```
   downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

          Uri uri = Uri.parse(downloadFileUrl);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);



    nameOfFile = URLUtil.guessFileName(urlChar, null,
            MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(urlChar));
    Log.e("url char", urlChar);

    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, nameOfFile);


    request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);   


    myDownloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    getProgressPercentaged();
}
```

And also insted  of progress bar If I want to show the download percentage like this image[image: Downloading with progress bar]

Comment: watch this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3OOpvbHzzo)

Comment: You need ProgressDialog with AsyncTask:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893626/how-to-use-asynctask-to-show-a-progressdialog-while-doing-background-work-in-and