# How to show Progress Bar as TextView loads?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, progress-bar

I know that I can set the layout for a screen to be a `progressBar` as long as I inflate the layout after all my content has loaded. Is there any way to set a `progressBar` to wait until a `TextView` has loaded? For example, if I need to grab some content from my database and as I grab the content, I'd like to show a `progressBar` in place of that `TextView`. I was thinking I could try to wrap every `TextView` that needs this `progressBar` in a `RelativeLayout` and just set the visibility whenever the call from the database is finished. Is there a better way to do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Query your database in AsyncTask, make progressbar visible in onPreExecute() & fill yout textview in onPostExecute() where you can hide your progressbar

Answer (score 1):

You can use Aysnc task to fetch data and make progress bar visible before fetching the data and hide it in onPostExecute method of async task.
refer this question
[How to use AsyncTask to show a ProgressDialog while doing background work in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893626/how-to-use-asynctask-to-show-a-progressdialog-while-doing-background-work-in-and)

Answer (score 0):

As Pallav mentioned the use of Async task can accomplish what you want.Check how to create an Async task and in these methods show/hide progressBar dialog.

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();  

        //showDialog() here;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //do what you want here//
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        //dismissDialog() here;//


    }
```