# How to Start same activity in edit as well as update mode in android?

Tags: android

i have one activity in which i enter some values and save it in the data base by calling webservise on save button.

basically i have two buttons in my app one for save and one for edit previous record . when clicking edit i want to open same activity that i use for save but by clicking edit i want show the previously entered value in activity after modifing that by user then back to data base, but i want to use same activity for edit as well

How can i achive this the same activity in edit mode as well  ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503458/update-view-at-runtime-in-android

Comment: kindly share your code that you have now.

Comment: basically i have two buttons in my app one for save and one for edit previous record . when clicking edit i want to open same activity that i use for save but by clicking edit i want show the previously entered value in activity after modifing that by user then back to data base, but i want to use same activity for edit as well

Comment: Thas wasn't code, it was explanation

Answer (score 0):

when clicked on save, open the database  insert the values and close the database
again open the database and read the values and display them by clearing the already shown values

When clicked on edit,open the database edit the values and close the database 
again open the database and read the values and display them by clearing the already shown values

then u will be in the same screen