# setContentView taking too much time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mapview, mapactivity

I have activity with MapView, TextView, 3 ImageButton and 1 simple Button. First call setContentView for this activity takes too much time (near 10 seconds). Here is my view code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="0px" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_route_info"
        android:apiKey="MyAPIKeyGoesHere"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_accept"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="2dip"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="@string/btn_accept" />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="0px" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_route_info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textEdit"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="0px" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_zoom_in"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/btn_zoom_in_content_descriptor"
            android:src="@drawable/zoom_in" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_zoom_out"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/btn_zoom_out_content_descriptor"
            android:src="@drawable/zoom_out" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_my_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/btn_my_location_content_descriptor"
            android:src="@drawable/my_location" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have no idea what can slow activity loading so much. I've read this topic: [setContentView taking long time (10-15 seconds) to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180072/setcontentview-taking-long-time-10-15-seconds-to-execute) 
but i still can't solve my problem. If you can give me any hint or idea, I would be thankful.

**UPDATE:**

onCreate method from my activity code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.google_map_view);
    mapView = (MapView) this.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (locationManager == null) {
        this.finish();
        return;
    }

    final MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    myLocationOverlay.disableCompass();
    myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();

    acceptBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_accept);
    final View.OnClickListener acceptBtnListener = new AcceptBtnListener();
    acceptBtn.setOnClickListener(acceptBtnListener);

    final ImageButton zoomInBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_zoom_in);
    final ImageButton zoomOutBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_zoom_out);
    myLocationBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_my_location);
    zoomInBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mapController.zoomIn();
        }
    });

    zoomOutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mapController.zoomOut();
        }
    });

    myLocationBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final GeoPoint myLocation = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation();
            if (myLocation != null) {
                mapController.animateTo(myLocation);
                mapController.setCenter(myLocation);
            } else {
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(GoogleMapActivity.this, "", getString(R.string.dlg_progress_obtaining_location), true);
            }
        }
    });

    mapController = this.mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(MAP_ZOOM_LEVEL);

    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    isInRouteMode = intent.getBooleanExtra("isRouteMode", false);  //activity started to display route?
    if (isInRouteMode) {
        final String fromAddress = intent.getStringExtra("fromAddress");
        final String toAddress = intent.getStringExtra("toAddress");
        final GeoPoint fromPoint;
        final GeoPoint toPoint;
        try {
            fromPoint = getGeoPointByAddressString(fromAddress, this);
            toPoint = getGeoPointByAddressString(toAddress, this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.err_geocoder_not_available),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(CLASSTAG, e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        new RouteCalculationTask().execute(fromPoint, toPoint);
    } else {  //activity started to select address
        addressItemizedOverlay = new AddressItemizedOverlay(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red_pin));
        mapView.getOverlays().add(addressItemizedOverlay);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
        mapView.setOnTouchListener(new MapOnTouchListener());
    }
}
```

Priveous activity is simple activity with just four buttons so I belive it can't slow down this activity.

Comment: Use Traceview to determine precisely where your time is being consumed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what kind of view are you coming from?

The previous view/activity/fragment can slow things down, also the mapview can be slow especially when if GPS is trying to get a lock at the same time

consider a loading dialog