# Splash Text message on android

Tags: android, splash-screen

anybody please help me regarding in app crediting within android app, which show dialog message/splash text on app startup; like "hacked by RIU - WWW.ALPHAGAMER.ORG" as shown in the screenshot

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show splash image while loading activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179092/how-to-show-splash-image-while-loading-activity)

Answer (score 2):

Just do a Toast when the application is starting

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code to do this-

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hacked by Riu", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
```

You can use `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` for smaller duration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show `Toast`. get the running tasks using `ActivityManager`, get the top task and get the top activity from that task. if top activity package name is equal to the package name of target app, show the Toast. for this you need to run a `Service` and check for running tasks at regular intervals (might be for every 1 sec) and do validation as said...