# Android - loading a big Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, overloading

I am running an activity from another one but I have to inflate like 200 views so it takes 3-4 seconds to start. How do you recommend me to do? Should I make a loading screen? If yes, how hould I do that?

**EDIT:**  is it possible to load the onCreate() of an activity at the beggining of the app and show the activity later ?

Comment: This guy here had the same problems. Just take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179092/how-to-show-splash-image-while-loading-activity

Comment: why you have to use 200 views, can u share the screenshot.

Comment: No I will not share my app on internet. I want to publish my app. I have a simple xml with 3 or 4 views and then I inflate it 150 times more or less with a row that has one textview and 2 checkboxes

Comment: Are you making a list of views ?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not using ListView in purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should make a loading screen, 3-4 seconds are too long for a user to wait without a loading screen (most will think app is frozen and kill it).

You can try this:

1. put you interface into a fragment instead activity
2. load blank activity with setContentView()
3. launch a ProgressDialog or something else
4. inflate the fragment
5. when inflating is finished, display the fragmetn in the activity and dismiss   the dialog

Comment: You can't use a dialog while executing setContenView()

Comment: My bad, the "inflate" made me think he was using a fragment in the second activity.

Comment: And how should I know when the loading has finished?