# How could I start the startActivity() before startActivityForResult()

Tags: java, android, android-activity

When I execute the code the startActivity() is called only after the startActivityForResult() is over. How can I start the startActivity() first? I tried with threads but I didn't succeeded.

```
   // Splash Correct
   Intent correct = new Intent("com.quizcontest.alex.SPLASHCORRECT");
   startActivity(correct);

   Bundle b = new Bundle();
   Intent i = new Intent(StartPlaying.this, CorrectAnswer.class);
   b.putInt("p1Key", player1Score);
   b.putInt("p2Key", player2Score);
   b.putInt("rKey", round);
   i.putExtras(b);
   startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

Comment: What does 'Splash Correct' do?

Comment: @MisterSquonk this splash should pop-up for 1,5 seconds and the second activity should be called

Answer (score 1):

startActivity does not block.  It causes something to happen in a new thread, so it will immediately execute the lines that happen after it.

It seems like you are trying to show a splash screen.  See this other question related to spash screens: [Android SplashScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979524/android-splashscreen)  or this example for displaying a splash screen using a dialog: http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/01/01/android-splash-screens-done-right/

If the behavior you want is to start activity 1, and then start activity 2, the correct behavior is to start activity 1 for result.  Then onActivityResult will be called when activity 1 has completed.  At this point you can start activity 2.

Comment: The second activity is also startActivityForResult()

Comment: I resolved the problem. I put the splash activity in the second activity.