# Android splash screen simple and elegant way

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make a splash screen in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen-in-android)

Can any one tell me what is the simplest and most elegant way to create splash screen on android . I have seen many hackish way using timers (google search) etc.... Surely thats not elegant way?

Comment: By timers you mean "handler.postDelayed()"?

Comment: yep i been told to avoid handler / threads way of doing it.

Comment: Avoid using why, just cause you were told doesn't make this true...investigate the reason why I use that method extensively on each app, I have never had an issue with it yet.

Comment: Check my optimal and easy solution:
https://medium.com/@vatani.ahmad/android-optimal-splash-screen-without-extra-activity-or-fragment-b60fea45a0cc

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I'm posting this as an answer.

I'm not sure using SplashScreen is elegant at all. As already stated in [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen-in-android), you should use splashscreen if there is some background work that has to be done before showing user a GUI. If it's not necessary in your case, just make your app available for user's enjoyment as soon as possible.

Comment: Yes google gave me similar option it has tendency of going into infinite loop. Im keen to see dialog based solutions or something better.

Comment: I edited my answer, it doesn't make much sense now. Anyway, do you have something like [that](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/04/a-simple-android-splash-screen/) in mind?

Comment: Nope, again while loop not good idea.

Comment: Have you checked [last comment](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/04/a-simple-android-splash-screen/comment-page-2/#comment-25665)? It mentions using android animation as a splashscreen. Also, did you check the accepted answer on [the other question posted on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen-in-android)? And [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979524/android-splashscreen)?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use, my MainActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

public class mainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Thread lTimer = new Thread() {

        public void run() {

            try {
                int lTimer1 = 0;
                while (lTimer1 < 2000) {
                    sleep(100);
                    lTimer1 = lTimer1 + 100;
                }
                startActivity(new Intent("com.examples.MENU"));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally {
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    lTimer.start();
}

}
```

Which uses splash.xml where I add my splash image, then calls my Menu class. change `(lTimer1 < 2000)` to however long you want it to appear, 1000 = 1 second.

Comment: i found solution posted on this blog to be much elegant solution.

http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/01/01/android-splash-screens-done-right/