# What to return for an Async Task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have two functions that access the internet on the APP start. I've tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979524/android-splashscreen/1982002#comment11685166_1982002) post as a reference in order to have the popup dialog while my content loads.

The two functions I would use are:

```
getImage(); //Gets an image from the internet for an imageview
getJson();  //Where the app goes an parses a JSON object for a lazy load listview.
```

The problem I'm encountering with the post I referenced above is that I try to make the task return null but it causes the app to crash when I do this. So I have this:

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> {
protected Object doInBackground(String... args) {
    Log.i("MyApp", "Background thread starting");

    try {
        ImageView i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.currdoodlepic);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory
                .decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(imageURL)
                        .getContent());
        i.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    getJson("all");

    return "replace this with your data object";
}
```

I'm not sure what to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the exact answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090650/android-loading-an-image-from-the-web-with-asynctask). Here is the code:

```
ImageView mChart = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
String URL = "http://www...anything ...";

mChart.setTag(URL);
new DownloadImageTask.execute(mChart);
```

The Task class:

```
public class DownloadImagesTask extends AsyncTask<ImageView, Void, Bitmap> {

ImageView imageView = null;

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(ImageView... imageViews) {
    this.imageView = imageViews[0];
    return download_Image((String)imageView.getTag());
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
}


private Bitmap download_Image(String url) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type return of the method doInBackground depend of what you need at the post execution :

```
void postExecute(Object result); // AsyncTask method
```

Parameter "result" is the return value of doInBackground. So if you need nothing you return NULL.

Comment: Are your sure that the crash is here ? And if not, do you use postExecute ?