# Show splash screen until app is done loading

Tags: java, android, xml, android-asynctask, splash-screen

My app loads a lot of stuff on startup and after testing it delays too long at the beginning to not have a `splash screen`.  So, I want to display a `splash screen` until my app is done loading.  I do NOT want to display a screen with a timer for X seconds.  I found an example here:

[Android SplashScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979524/android-splashscreen)

I tried implementing the code in the SO topic above but I just don't understand the code.  After integrating it in my code I come up with one error that I commented into the code below.  But I don't understand a lot of the code and I have commented in the code below the parts I am confused by.

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog pd = null;
    private Object data = null;  //What is this?

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);

        // show the ProgressDialog on this thread
        this.pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Working...", "Downloading data...", true, false);

        // start a new thread that will download all the data
        new DownloadTask().execute("Any parameters to download.");  //What is DownloadTask()?
    }

    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> {

        protected Object doInBackground(String... args) {  //Are these parameters correct?
            return "replace this with your object";  //What is this?
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Object results) {
            // pass the resulting data to the main activity
            MainMenu.this.data = result;  //Error:  "result cannot be resolved to a variable"

            if(MainMenu.this.pd != null) {
                MainMenu.this.pd.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is why you shouldn't blindly take some code and run it. You must understand what you're doing and only after knowing what each piece of code does, use it. I suggest you learn android basics(specially [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)) and then try to comprehend the code again. I'm sure you'll be able to answer almost everything by yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with the error:

```
MainMenu.this.data = result;
```

Notice the typo? It should be result*s*:

```
MainMenu.this.data = results;
```

Addressing the rest of your questions below:

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object>
```

The declaration is for an inline class called `DownloadTask`, and it states that you'll be taking `String`s (via `String...`) as parameters to your `doInBackground(String... params)`.

The second parameter (`Void` in your case) indicates the datatype used to "publish" the progress via `publishProgress(DATATYPE)`/`onProgressUpdate(DATATYPE... progress)`. This method is suitable for notifying the user of changes, for example when you've finished downloading a file but still have a few to go.

The last parameter (`Object`), indicates what type of data you'll be passing on to `onPostExecute(DATATYPE)`, in this example `Object`. This could either be to update a ListAdapter somewhere, or trigger any other UI change based on the outcome of the actions done in `doInBackground`.

Answer (score 2):

Show `ProgressDialog` in `onPreexecute` and dismiss it in `onPostExcute` methods

something like this

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> {

           @Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
  mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    mProgressDialog =ProgressDialog.show(activity, "", "Please Wait",true,false);
    super.onPreExecute();
}

        protected Object doInBackground(String... args) {  //Are these parameters correct?
            return "replace this with your object";  //What is this?
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Object results) {
            // pass the resulting data to the main activity
            MainMenu.this.data = results;  //it should be results 
if (mProgressDialog != null || mProgressDialog.isShowing()){
         mProgressDialog.dismiss();
 }
            if(MainMenu.this.pd != null) {
                MainMenu.this.pd.dismiss();
            }
        }
```

Comment: And also edited results is the value you are returning in doinBackground