# Android splash screen: how to make it centered?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-resources

I use a theme-based solution as it described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7057332/540639), for example, 
to show a splash screen in my application.
Here is my background_launch.xml:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/launch_image"
android:tileMode="disabled" />
```

When I have `launch_image` as png everything is OK. But the app crashes if I use `@drawable/layerlist` instead of `@drawable/launch_image`.
layerlist.xml is:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/launch_image"
            android:tileMode="disabled" >
        </bitmap>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The app crashed with the following log (several lines are skipped):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.glu.pathlight/com.glu.pathlight.JSFinalNativeActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/background_launch.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020000
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        ...
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/background_launch.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020000
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2096)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #18: <bitmap> requires a valid src attribute
    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.inflate(BitmapDrawable.java:571)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2092)
    ... 22 more
```

What is wrong in my resources?

Comment: this question is misleading, you are asking about using resources and embedding an image inside a layerlist not asking how to center an image inside the screen

Comment: `<bitmap> requires a valid src attribute` because you are passing `layer-list` in `src` of `<bitmap>` instead of image drawable name

Comment: The problem is that background_launch.xml was not found. What resource is referencing that? Perhaps you need to clean your project and build it again.

Comment: @3amoura You may be right. From the one side the question is about using resources, but from the other it solves a particular case I faced. Feel free to suggest another header for this question, I'm ready to change it for the future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/launch_image"
        android:tileMode="disabled" >
    </bitmap>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

in your `background_launch.xml` instead of trying to reference a state list in `android:src` for `<bitmap\>`

A state list is not a bitmap -- that's what the error's telling you.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have changed android:src="@drawable/launch_image" to android:src="@drawable/layerlist".